# Assigning the state of a component to variables in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. I was wondering how I would assign the state (`this.state`) to a set of variables `busNumber`,`busTime`,`busName`.

I saw that it might be possible by doing:

`let { busNumber, busTime, busName } = this.state;`

But I'm not sure exactly how that works. What is inside the state object that allows it to retrieve this information automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> let { busNumber, busTime, busName } = this.state;

This syntax is called "destructuring". It's not unique to react, but instead is a part of ECMAScript 2015 (one of the newer versions of javascript). It's a shorthand for:

```
let busNumber = this.state.busNumber;
let busTime = this.state.busTime;
let busName = this.state.busName;
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: coming back to this answer a year later, I look like an idiot! :)